# Mousing over RichEditableTextField causes scrolling to stop

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, mouse, richeditabletext

I have noticed that if a `VScrollBar` component contains `RichEditableTextField`s then when I am scrolling the component, and the mouse falls over a text field, then the component stops scrolling because the mouse cursor has changed and the mouse focus is on the text field. (even though I haven't given focus to the field by clicking on it).

This feels pretty buggy and I'm wondering if there is a way around it?

**Edit:** I should add that this only happens on Mac OSX when using the touchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed in the 4.6 SDK. The workaround is to update your SDK version.